# Proper way to remove all series data from a highcharts chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

UPDATE: Here's a jsfiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pynju/1/

Click on the blue column on Monday. When the detail-view loads, notice that 01-07 have 3 columns (expected 2). Click on the tallest bar to go back to the original view. Notice that the labels on the xAxis aren't being removed.

===============

I have a bar chart that has 2 series, displayed as pairs of bars, side by side.

```
series: [{
         showInLegend: false,
         data: dowChartData
      },{
         showInLegend: false,
         data: avgUserDowChartData
      }],
```

.

```
dowChartData = [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   {
                y: 98.74,
                color: '#0072ff',
                drilldown: {
                   name: 'Category Engagement - Sunday',
                   categories: ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23'],
                   data: [0,637,0,0,0,173,48.54,48.54,0,0,0,0,0,0,102.24,166.36,706.59,699.18,298.32,184.14,97.08,1539,0,1224.56],
                   color: '#0072ff',
                   data2: [506.80686467275,354.56354558498,333.25158689567,234.19283190879,234.82132336088,220.03247578171,222.86420797556,218.14034615202,170.42559544164,171.54776353196,249.24788461442,345.14915669555,206.65543589797,243.38811965637,367.02593304906,378.83677778129,467.45739743621,424.26264387522,639.60922934374,679.71299714907,373.26353846375,480.94380626458,551.82326068362,466.77469230724],
                   color2: '#C00'
                }
             }
AND SIMILAR
```

.

```
avgUserDowChartData = [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         {
                y: 142.35,
                color: '#C00'
             },
AND SIMILAR
```

The initial data is day of week data with the X-axis being: Sunday - Monday - Tues - Wed - Thurs - Fri - Saturday

The initial series has a drilldown element with a new data & data2
(see above)

Using the drilldown demo code as an example, I have this code in place:

```
column: {
              borderWidth: 0,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
               events: {
                  click: function(event) {
                     var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                     if (drilldown) { // drill down
                        setChart(dowChart, drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color, drilldown.data2, drilldown.color2);
                     } else { // restore
                        setChart(dowChart, '', dowCategories, dowChartData);
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
```

Set chart handler:

```
function setChart(chart, name, categories, data, color, data2, color2) {
      chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
//      chart.series[0].remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
          chart.series[i].remove();
      }
      chart.addSeries({
         showInLegend: false,
         name: name,
         data: data,
         color: color || 'white'
      });
      if (typeof(data2) != undefined && data2.length > 0) {
          chart.addSeries({
             showInLegend: false,
             name: name,
             data: data2,
             color: color2 || 'white'
          });
      }
   }
```

The initial chart display perfectly fine:
[image: initial display]

When you click on any of the blue bars (the data set that has the drilldown), things get wonky for the first 7 x-axis items:
[image: drill down - broken display]

It's as if the initial data sets aren't being removed by the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
          chart.series[i].remove();
      }
```

When you click on any of the bars with the intention of resetting to the original data set/series:
[image: reset data to original set - broken display]

So... it's clear that the remove series code I'm using isn't working. What's the best way to completely remove the data on the chart and the 2 series I need to display each time depending on what is clicked?

Comment: When are you calling your removal code?

Comment: It's being called when a column from the original chart is clicked. It's a part of setData() that gets called in point -> events -> click

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Try this to remove all chart series,

```
while(chart.series.length > 0)
    chart.series[0].remove(true);
```

it works for me. the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++)
```

won't work because the `chart.series.length` is decreased each time `remove()` is called. That way, the `i` will never reach the expected length.

Comment: Your while loop could accidentally get an auto-inserted semi-colon on the while loop. You should make it all one line or use braces.

Comment: This totally worked for me. It's a very insightful solution, what with noticing the change in length. Thank you!

Comment: You're correct in saying the for loop you listed "for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) won't work because the chart.series.length is decreased each time...", but you can simply start from the end of the series: for(var i = chart.series.length - 1; i > -1; i--). I like this route because StockCharts uses the first or second series as the navigator and I can update that series while keeping all of the "Navigator" attributes attached to it. See my answer below.

Comment: I've been stuck with this issue for 3 days. THANKS A LOT @Lee !

Comment: In general when removing from an array one should count down: `var i = arr.length;while(--i>-1){if(true){arr.splice(i,1)}}` Works all the time even if one just wants to remove some of the data from the array.

Comment: I had to use chart.highcharts() instead of chart. Where I initialised it like this: chart = $('#line-chart').highcharts({ blabla });

Comment: While the above answer is correct, the following is the most performant way of removing all series:  `var i = chart.series.length; while(i--) { chart.series[i].remove(); }`

Comment: What if series has more than 1 element and you want remove all of them. Which is the case with a multi-layered pie (donut) chart.

Answer (score 43):

The following way the chart will not redraw every iteration.
So you'll get a better performance.

```
while( chart.series.length > 0 ) {
    chart.series[0].remove( false );
}

chart.redraw();
```

Comment: Read something similar elsewhere, however they used: "while(chart.series.length) chart.series[0].remove(false);"
Not a big difference, just four characters, but it works

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem with initing scatter plots (< 2500 points).

Answer (score 9):

Another way to remove all series in HighCharts with a for loop is to start from the end. Here's how to do it:

```
var seriesLength = chart.series.length;
for(var i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    chart.series[i].remove();
}
```

I prefer to go this route because when using a HighStock chart, the navigator is usually the first series. I also prefer to keep a variable set to the navigator series. In that case, I'll do the following:

```
var seriesLength = chart.series.length;
var navigator;
for(var i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if(chart.series[i].name.toLowerCase() == 'navigator') {
        navigator = chart.series[i];
    } else {
        chart.series[i].remove();
    }
}
```

Now I can easily set the navigator series.

Here's an example of removing all series from a Highchart: 
http://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/srZU2/

Here's an example of resetting a HighStock chart with new data (including the navigator series):
http://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/WcLQc/

Comment: Thank you ! I was wondering why my navigator was messed up ! (ps: it seems to be Navigator, with a capital N now)

Comment: And it looks like in the newest version of Stock charts the navigator series might not be the first series anymore. But with this method you can still keep track of it and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++)` doesn't work is because you're modifying the array while you're looping over it. To get around this, you can iterate over the array from right to left, so when you remove an element, the index of the array will still point to the last item in the array.

Using lodash's [forEachRight](https://lodash.com/docs#forEachRight), you can do:

```
_.forEachRight(chart.series, chartSeries => {
  chartSeries.remove(false);
});

chart.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a simple matter of telling the chart to redraw. When you remove a series, try forcing the chart to redraw:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
    chart.series[i].remove(true); //forces the chart to redraw
}
```

Comment: Thanks, updated the code but it's still broken on drilldown (and subsequent reset attempt)

Comment: Updated the question with an interactive example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/pynju/1/

Answer (score 0):

`var seriesLength = chart.series.length;
for(var i = seriesLength -1; i > -1; i--) {
    chart.series[i].remove();
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also update and add a new series and if the new series is less than the current series then remove the series:

```
var hChart = $("#Chart").highcharts();

for (var i = 0; i < newSeries.length; i++) { //UPDATE-OLD/ADD-NEW SERIES
    if (hChart.series[i])
        hChart.series[i].update(newSeries[i]);
    else
        hChart.addSeries(newSeries[i]);
}

var serieslen = newSeries.length;
if (hChart.series[serieslen]) {
    var loopfrm = hChart.series.length - 1;
    for (var i = loopfrm; i >= serieslen; i--) {//REMOVE SERIES
        hChart.series[loopfrm].remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the working solution. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
   chart.series[0].remove();
}
chart.redraw();
```

It will completely remove all series.

Comment: this doesn't work, as chart.series.length is modified at each iteration