# How to Redraw HighChart After Dropdown Value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, series

I have a `drop down menu` called `info` and I want to update my highchart everytime a user selects a value through the `info menu`.

Here is the code:

```
$('#info').on('change', function() {

  add_info(this.value);

});
```

The `add_info()` method simply gets data via ajax and this is how I am processing it after getting the `response` back:

```
if(chart=='stacked_chart'){

    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

          var series = [{name:'Coached',data:[]},{name:'Non Coached',data:[],stack: 'yes'},{name:'Delta',data:[],stack: 'yes'}],
          year, month, day;


            for(var i=0; i<response.length;i++){ 

                var d = response[i].date.split(",");
                year = parseFloat(d[0]);
                month = parseFloat(d[1])-1; //date.utc method starts month 0-11
                day = parseFloat(d[2]);
                var coached = +(parseFloat(response[i].coached).toFixed(3)); 
                var non_coached = +(parseFloat (response[i].non_coached).toFixed(3));
                var delta = +(parseFloat (response[i].delta).toFixed(3));

                series[0].data.push([Date.UTC(year,month,day),coached]);
                series[1].data.push([Date.UTC(year,month,day),non_coached]);
                series[2].data.push([Date.UTC(year,month,day),delta]);
                console.log(Date.UTC(year,month,day));
            }

                  console.log(series);

          if(series.length){

           stacked_chart.userOptions.series = series;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(stacked_chart.userOptions);
            console.log(chart.series[0].data[0].options);
            console.log(chart.series[1].data[0].options);
            console.log(chart.series[2].data[0].options);


          }
    }
```

I can see it brings back the new data but It doesn't redraw. I have looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604291/proper-way-to-remove-all-series-data-from-a-highcharts-chart) but couldn't redraw the chart. Any ideas how to reset the chart every time a user selects a new value from the drop down?

Comment: There are a number of ways depending on the details of what you want. It will be much easier to help with a fiddle example. If you are providing entirely new series and data from the user selection, I would simply destroy the chart and build a new one.

Comment: ok I have sorted it out by bringing the chart definition inside the ajax response processing method. thanks for your help