# Issue with highcharts on jsfiddle where series is not being removed on drillup

Tags: jquery, highcharts, jsfiddle, highmaps

The Demo I am basing my project on is [here](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown).

I have changed this around for my own country and information but the problem exists here for the drillup function.

Reproduction steps:
Open the jsfiddle in the link above and click on CA (california) in the map, then click the button '< Back to USA'

Next click somewhere else on the West coast to see that the california drilldown has not been removed from the map. I need these to be removed once the back button is clicked.

[image: issue with old map showing outside selection]

Here is the main body of the code:

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {

                if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                    var chart = this,
                        mapKey = 'countries/us/' + e.point.drilldown + '-all',
                        // Handle error, the timeout is cleared on success
                        fail = setTimeout(function () {
                            if (!Highcharts.maps[mapKey]) {
                                chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-frown"></i> Failed loading ' + e.point.name);

                                fail = setTimeout(function () {
                                    chart.hideLoading();
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        }, 3000);

                    // Show the spinner
                    chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-3x"></i>'); // Font Awesome spinner

                    // Load the drilldown map
                    $.getScript('https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/' + mapKey + '.js', function () {

                        data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps[mapKey]);

                        // Set a non-random bogus value
                        $.each(data, function (i) {
                            this.value = i;
                        });

                        // Hide loading and add series
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        clearTimeout(fail);
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
                            name: e.point.name,
                            data: data,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{point.name}'
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }


                this.setTitle(null, { text: e.point.name });
            },
            drillup: function () {
                this.setTitle(null, { text: 'USA' });
            }
        }
    },
```

I know of one way of doing it, and this is by doing a window.history.go(-1) in the drillup function but this removes the zooming graphics and breaks the button after one click. history.go(-1) doesn't break the button but does not work properly after one click either.

I have found a similar issue here: [Proper way to remove all series data from a highcharts chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604291/proper-way-to-remove-all-series-data-from-a-highcharts-chart) but this deals with a bar chart so the code is different.

The solution for this issue is to change

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++)
```

to

```
while(chart.series.length > 0)
chart.series[0].remove(true);
```

I had thought that not saving the cache on jsfiddle could solve this too but I could not get that working either.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a regression bug from 5.0.3 to 5.0.4 version. It is fixed in the latest development version, so use 5.0.3/latest github version.

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/master/highmaps.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/maps/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsjLp3h1/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/5.0.3/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/5.0.3/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsjLp3h1/1/